# Select MySQL rows where month is December

Tags: php, mysql, substring

My date format is `year-month-day`, (e.g. `2013-12-01`)

And I want to get all rows that have '12' as the month.

I'm currently using this query but nothing happens:

```
$checkadd = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM awsalesreport WHERE (SUBSTRING(date, 5, 2) = '12')");
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Hint: You should now accept one of the answers provided.

Answer (score 3):

Use [MONTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function for a datetime/date type.

```
SELECT * FROM awsalesreport WHERE MONTH(`date`) = 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [MONTH() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month):

```
SELECT * FROM `awsalesreport` WHERE MONTH(`date`) = 12
```